# Integer solutions for Fermat Last Theorem like equation: $x^n+y^n=z^n+n$.

Tags: number-theory

I was wondering about this equation $x^n+y^n=z^n+n$ for integer solutions. I managed to find integer solutions pretty easily when $n=1,2,3$, but for $n=4,5$ I did not seem to find any. Is that the case? I tried to look at this equation modulo small primes to find some sort of contradictions that this equality cannot hold but didn't find any so far. Any suggestions?

Comment: For $n=4$, the left hand side is $0$, $1$, or $2$ mod $8$, while the right hand side is $4$ or $5$. This approach also rules out solutions for $n=6$ and infinitely many other even numbers (namely those congruent to $4$ or $6$ mod $8$).  It doesn't work at all for odd numbers, though.

Answer (score 1):

Extending a comment to a full-fledged answer, the cases $n=4$ and $n=5$ can be ruled out by looking at the corresponding equations mod $8$ and $11$, respectively.

For $n=4$, the left hand side is $0$, $1$, or $2$ mod $8$, while the right hand side is $4$ or $5$.

For $n=5$, the left hand side is $0$, $\pm1$, or $\pm2$ mod $11$, while the right hand side is $4$, $5$, or $6$. (This is because the fifth power of any integer is congruent to $0$, $1$, or $-1$ mod $11$.)

The mod $8$ argument works for any even number congruent to $4$ or $6$ mod $8$. A mod-$11$-style argument works any time $2n+1$ is prime (with $n\gt3$).